# Highlighting text with PdfObject as only reference

Tags: itext, highlight

I'm using iTextSharp and I have the `PdfObject` which contains the text, I want to highlight. More specifically, I have a *stream* object that is used as an external object (a *Form XObject*) in one or more pages. I was able to create a `PdfStamper` instance, but I need the actual coordinates of this object to set the color. What's the best approach to go about this?

I was able to parse the PDF using a RenderListener but was wondering if this was possible by iterating through the XObjects.

Comment: Define "the PDFObject" which contains the text. Is it a direct object or an indirect object. If an indirect object, do you have its object number? It's a strange question. I'd assume that you'd have the operator that positions and draws the string. There's no such thing as "a PDFObject which contains the text." Obviously, that text is somewhere in a content stream object, but stream objects are either the entire page or XObjects. It's really hard to tell what you are talking about. I'll vote to close the question until you clarify.

Comment: I got the PdfObject by iterating through the XObjects.

Comment: @peacefullearnet OK, I updated your question, but it's still unclear to me: an XObject can be used in more than one page. Do you want to highlight the XObject in all the pages where it's used, or do you want to highlight it only on a specific page?

Comment: Furthermore, is there a chance the Xobject will later be reused? And should the word automatically be marked even there? In that case you may consider "highlighting" the word in the Xobject content stream itself.

Comment: *I got the PdfObject by iterating through the XObjects.* - did you iterate through the Xobjects of a page? Or did you also iterate through the Xobjects of other Xobjects or patterns or of annotations?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I only need to highlight it on the current occurrence/page

Comment: @mkl if I could "highlight" the words in Xobject through the stream that would be great. I might be referring to Xobjects wrong but the way I'm looping through them is getting every PdfObject by index that is less than the XrefSize of the PdfReader.

Comment: If you loop over all the objects in the xref table looking for Form XObjects, there is no "current occurrence/page."

Comment: Actually,  if you loop over all objects, you don't know if that object is used at all.

Comment: *I might be referring to Xobjects wrong* - If you are not sure, please consider sharing the PDF in question and indicating the object which you have recognized to hold your text.

Comment: @mkl I tried updating the post with my attached pdf but wasn't able to. It was just a test pdf I made through Microsoft word with 2 pictures and 2 strings. I can correctly get everything with RenderListeners, a little broken up but manageable, and with XObjects, I successfully found 4 streams but didn't know how to get the actual content or rectangle coordinates from them